# C# WPF Directory Treeview with checkboxes: check items on building fails with empty PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

In a WPF window I show a treeview with checkboxes with disks/directories on a Pc. When the user expands a node, an event calls folder_Expanded adding the subdirectories of that node.

What should happen is that certain directories show a color (this works) and certain directories are checked if they are found in a XML file. The user can then check or uncheck (sub)directories after which the modified directory selection is again stored in that xml file.

However, I can't get a checkbox in that treeviewitem checked with a certain directory. In the code of the expanded event, I test it with a sample directory. The background color works fine, but the IsSelected line is doing nothing. Reason is that PropertyChanged is null so it doesn't create an instance of PropertyChangedEventArgs. I would say I have everything: a model inheriting from INotifyPropertyChanged and assigned as DataContext in the XAML and setting the property IsChecked of the CheckBox as defined in the XAML via this model.
What do I miss?

Alternatively I would like to know if I can **directly** set the checkbox to checked, without databinding, like I set the background color? Problem with databinding is when it doesn't work there's no way to debug the code, it just doesn't work....

At the start:

```
    SelectFilesModel selectFilesModel = new SelectFilesModel();
    public SelectFiles()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Window_Loaded();
    }


    void folder_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)sender;
        if (item.Items.Count == 1 && item.Items[0] == dummyNode)
        {
            item.Items.Clear();
            try
            {
                foreach (string s in Directory.GetDirectories(item.Tag.ToString()))
                {
                    TreeViewItem subitem = new TreeViewItem();
                    subitem.Header = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                    subitem.Tag = s;
                    subitem.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
                    subitem.Items.Add(dummyNode);
                    subitem.Expanded += new RoutedEventHandler(folder_Expanded);
                    if (s.ToLower() == "c:\\temp") // Sample directory to test
                    {
                        subitem.Background = Brushes.Yellow; // This works!
                        selectFilesModel.IsChecked = true;   // Eventually PropertyChanged is always null!!
                    }
                    item.Items.Add(subitem);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e2.Message + " " + e2.InnerException);
            }

        }
    }
```

The XAML looks as follows:

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:SelectFilesModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <TreeView x:Name="foldersItem" SelectedItemChanged="foldersItem_SelectedItemChanged" Width="Auto" Background="#FFFFFFFF" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Name="img"  Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" 
                                       Source="{Binding 
                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                       Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                       AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, 
                                       Path=Header, 
                                       Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}"       
                                       />
                                    <TextBlock Name="DirName" Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0" />
<CheckBox Name="cb" Focusable="False" IsThreeState="True"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>                              </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
```

and the model looks as follows:

```
public class SelectFilesModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    bool? _isChecked = false;
    public bool? IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set { this.SetIsChecked(value, true, true); }
    }

    void SetIsChecked(bool? value, bool updateChildren, bool updateParent)
    {
        if (value == _isChecked)
            return;
        _isChecked = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
    }

    
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
    }
} // SelectFilesModel
```

Comment: You have two instances of SelectFilesModel, one declared in XAML as the DataContext of the Window, and another one created in code behind. Remove the XAML declaration and set `DataContext = selectFilesModel;` in the SelectFiles constructor.

Comment: Thanks Clemens, but I tried that as well already (added the XAML code later). Still PropertyChanged remains null. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to see how youuu initialize the TreeView. It really looks like the `selectFilesModel` is not source of any data binding. It's not even part of your tree.

You are adding `TreeViewItem` manually (which is not a good idea - see your problem, which wouldn't exist if you would focus on dealing with the data models instead). Because of adding `TreeViewItem` elements directly, the `DataContext` of the `TreeViewItem` is the item itself.
The `DataContext` of your `HeaderTemplate` is the header value, which in your case is a `string`. You see `selectFilesModel` is never involved.
`CheckBox.IsChecked` currently binds to this string and we all know `string` has no property `IsChecked`.

What you should do is to create the tree using `SelectFilesModel`.

The following example is your modified code. It is not tested and written with no editor so it may contain minor erros. It should be enough to show the pattern.

Also note that `Directory.EnumerateDirectories` will perform much better in your scenario than `Directory.GetDirectories`.

Create an enum to express different states. Each state will map to a color which you set in XAML using a trigger.

```
enum DirectoryState
{
  Default = 0,
  Special
}
```

Then modify `SelectFilesModel` to allow to reference its children (subdirectories) and add a `State` enum property

```
public class SelectFilesModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // TODO::Implement constructor to initialize properties

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    bool? _isChecked = false;
    public bool? IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set { this.SetValue(value, ref _isChecked, true, true); }
    }

    DirectoryState _state;
    public DirectoryState State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set { this.SetValue(value, ref _state, true, true); }
    }

    string _path;
    public string Path
    {
        get { return _path; }
        set { this.SetValue(value, ref _path, true, true); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SelectFilesModel> Subdirectories { get; }

    void SetValue<TValue>(TValue value, ref TValue field, bool updateChildren, bool updateParent, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (value == field)
            return;
        field = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertName);
    }
    
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
}
```

Then build the tree using the model. Note that since `Expanded` is a routed event, you don't have to subscribe to each item explicitly. Just listen to the routed event.

```
ObservableCollection<SelectFilesModel> TreeRoot { get; }
public SelectFiles()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Window_Loaded();

    foldersItem.AddHandler(TreeViewItem.ExpandedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(folder_Expanded)));
    TreeRoot = new ObservableCollection<SelectFilesModel>() { new SelectFilesModel() };
    foldersItem.ItemsSource = TreeRoot;
}


void folder_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (sender as TreeViewItem).DataContext as SelectFilesModel;
    if (item.Subdirectories.Count == 1 && item.Subdirectories[0] == dummyNode)
    {
        item.Subdirectories.Clear();
        try
        {
            foreach (string s in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(item.Path))
            {
                var subitem = new SelectFilesModel() { Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(s) };
                subitem.Subdirectories.Add(dummyNode);

                if (subitem.Path.ToLower() == "c:\\temp") // Sample directory to test
                {
                    subitem.State = DirectoryState.Special; // This works!
                    subitem.IsChecked = true;   // This should work too
                }
                item.Subdirectories.Add(subitem);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e2.Message + " " + e2.InnerException);
        }

    }
}
```

Finally define the data temnplate with the appropriate triggers and add it to e.g. `TreeView.Resources`:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SelectFilesModel} 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Subdirectories}">

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Name="img"  Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" 
                                   Source="{Binding 
                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                   Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                   AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, 
                                   Path=Header, 
                                   Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}"       
                                   />
                                <TextBlock Name="DirName" Text="{Binding Path}" Margin="5,0" />
    <CheckBox Name="cb" Focusable="False" IsThreeState="True"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>                                                </StackPanel>


  <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="{x:Static DirectoryState.Special}">
         <Setter TargetName="DirName" Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
     </DataTrigger>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hello BionicCode, Thank you for all this work and also: I am impressed that you produced all this code without an editor. It will take some time for me to check & implement this so I'll be back to comment later. The reason I added the TreeView manually was that I thought that otherwise you read the whole directory structure of a PC in a OC which takes more time than just adding the directories of an expanded node, but I see you still do that. I'll let you know soon!

Comment: Yes, you can still read the directories level by level. This is data logic and should always be decoupled from UI logic. But i highly recommend to use the `Directory.EnumerateDirectories` overload that accepts the [`EnumerationsOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions?view=net-5.0), which when `EnumerationsOptions.IgnoreInaccessible` is set to `true` avoids `UnauthorizedAccessException` when trying to access a forbidden directory during enumeration. But note that this overload is only available in .NET 5 (I think .NET Core and Standard too).

Comment: After clearing (only) a few issues with the code, e.g. a missing quot at the HierarchicalDataTemplate , I could start the program but got an exception "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource". Searching learned that this is a hard-to-find XAML issue. I finally gave up and restarted this screen as a Winforms screen. There checking the checkboxes (and text colors) + reading them worked. And without the need for databinding which is IMO often causing issues which can not be debugged, reason I avoid it when possible. Nevertheless thanks for your effort!